# Load txt file Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm trying to import txt file into my project, I've tried many methods and none seems to be working. Here's my example code, I try to load *"dane.txt"* file:

```
import Foundation

struct FileManager{
    static func loadFile(){
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "dane", ofType: "txt") {
            do {
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
                print(filepath)
                print(contents)
            } catch {
                print("Contents could not be loaded.")
            }
        } else {
            print("File dane.txt not found.")
        }
    }
}
```

Also I've modified custom working directory in scheme (same to project file, where I've put my .txt file). Nevertheless, still not getting file path.
Any ideas?

Comment: At least print the **real** error `print(error)` rather than a meaningless literal string. And you are discouraged from using `FileManager` as a custom struct name.

Comment: Okay, got error printer in catch block and modified struct name, the else block still runs, so filepath variable is nil value

Comment: Then the file in the bundle does not exist. Check Target Membership of the file in project navigator.

Comment: check the case is correct and use the `url(forResource:withExtension:)` before you try again.

Comment: I opened this panel, and I can see there, that in in Target Membership block I don't have checkmarked my scheme (other f.e. source files are checked), but I cannot check it - other files i can check/uncheck.

Comment: Now I tried to remove reference from my project of txt file, and then add again with checkmarked scheme, but no change in results for chosen scheme (I have only one in this project)

Comment: Go to `Build Phases` → `Copy Bundle Resources`. Do you see your txt file here?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have not added dane.txt file to the main bundle.

1. Click on project name in the left sidebar.
2. Select your target.
3. Choose Build Phases tab.
4. Expand Copy Bundle Resources
5. If you do not see dane.txt file add it by pressing `+`.

Comment: Still not getting the directory after your instructions

Comment: Could you upload your project?

Comment: Why did you add ios tag? You are developing macOS command line app. It doesn't have a bundle and you can't embed txt file in it.

Comment: Not sure what tag in this case is. And how could I embed txt file into macOS project?

Comment: Put TXT file near executable file. Use FileManager class to read TXT file.

Comment: Well, created project with cocoa, and it finally worked, and solved my problem. Anyways, still I'm wondering, why bundle doesn't work with command line app...

Comment: Because command line app doesn't have a Bundle. Command line app is one executable file. Bundle it's a folder with .app extension that has a lot of files including one executable file. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle)